# Forward in form action

Tags: jsp

I used

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
```

to get username parameter from previous jsp file. Now I want to forward that parameter to another jsp file. Can I use the following code?

```
<form name="location" method="post" action=<jsp:forward page="storelatlong.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="username" value="<%= username %>"/></jsp:forward>>
```

Comment: `form` is for client like browsers. Where as `forward` operation is done at server. So `form` is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use `<form>` tag for this?

```
<jsp:forward page="storelatlong.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="username" value="<%= username %>" ></jsp:param>
</jsp:forward>
```

**On button event:**

```
<form action="storelatlong.jsp"  method="post" name="myform">
   --Your Other Elements
     <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%= username %>"/>
   -- button
</form>
```

**On storelatlong.jsp**

```
String userName = request.getParameter("username");
```

Comment: When i click on a button of type submit in the form, it has to be forwarded. So i used form. Is there any other way? Pls Help me out

Answer (score 0):

You have another choice. You can create a session variable and make it available to full application. Suppose if you want to pass it to multiple pages, then why you will use jsp forward.

```
session.setAttribute("user_name",username);
```

and in next page you can get it that by using,

```
session.getAttribute( "user_name" );
```